# Order of Element in Factor Group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Give the order of the element in the factor group:  $$26 + \langle 12 \rangle \text{ in }\mathbb Z_{60} /\langle 12 \rangle.\;    (26 + \langle 12 \rangle) = (2 + \langle 12 \rangle) = \{2, 14, 26, 38, 52\} $$ yeah? This has order $5$ so I think that $(26 + \langle 12 \rangle)$ has order 5 in $\mathbb Z_{60}/ \langle 12\rangle$
but that is wrong apparently. The answer is that it has order $6$. Why?

Comment: How did you get $5(2+\langle12\rangle)=0+\langle12\rangle$?

Answer (score 1):

It is the smallest $n$ for which $2n = 12$. So $n = 6$ is the order.

Answer (score 0):

Notice: If you multiply $2$ by $5$ you get $10$. If you multiply $2$ by $6$ you get $12$.

Answer (score 0):

<12>= {12, 24, 36, 48, 0}
Keep generating 26 until we find an element of <12> in <26>.
<26>={26, 52, 18, 44, 10, 36}
36 is in <12>, so we count the number of elements in the set which is 6.

So, the order is 6.